# Изменение размера "галочки" checkbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Уже не первый день бьюсь с данной мне проблемой. При изменении `FontSize` у `CheckBox` в WPF, текст изменяет свой размер, но окошко с галочкой остается без изменений. И очень неприятно работать с вот с таким вот контролом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В англоязычном SO нашёл вот такой кусочек разметки, которая как я понял переопределяет ПОЛНОСТЬЮ CheckBox. И где-то там и размеры окошка для галочки. Но галочка не меняет размер. И при добавлении вот этого кода в ресурсы (кода много, скрываю):

```html
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background"
                     Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border"
                     Color="#FF707070" />
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background"
                     Color="#FFF3F9FF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border"
                     Color="#FF5593FF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph"
                     Color="#FF212121" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background"
                     Color="#FFE6E6E6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border"
                     Color="#FFBCBCBC" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph"
                     Color="#FF707070" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background"
                     Color="#FFD9ECFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border"
                     Color="#FF3C77DD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph"
                     Color="#FF212121" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph"
                     Color="#FF212121" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    Margin="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="optionMark"
                                          Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z "
                                          Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"
                                          Margin="5"
                                          Opacity="0"
                                          Stretch="Uniform" />
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}"
                                               Margin="2"
                                               Opacity="0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              Grid.Column="1"
                                              Focusable="False"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding"
                                    Value="4,-1,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="optionMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="optionMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="optionMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                                    Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    TargetName="optionMark"
                                    Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                                    Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    TargetName="optionMark"
                                    Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                    TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

CheckBox обретает вот такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется что лучше, но до тех пор пока не поставишь галочку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как то выглядит не очень. Как по мне выглядит это примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю ясно описал проблему. Спасибо за выделенное время для меня.

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать нестандартные размеры шрифтов и галочек? Чтобы центрировать галочек по вертикали, надо установить VerticalContentAlignment

Comment: А чем Вас не устроили другие ответы на en.SO ([How to make checkbox bigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13481275)). Почему остановились именно на этом?